# Linking to an external css file

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

i have been trying to link a css file i created in my local computer to my html code but it doesn't seem to work.  Where should we keep the css file we want to link in our html code or how should we link to that file? As an example i am posting this html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Breeding Dogs—Tips about Alsatians</title>
  <meta name="description" content="How to breed Alsatians, tips on proper breeding and information about common issues with this breed.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Dogs,Alsatian,Breeding,Dog,Tips,Free,Pet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="printstyles.css">
  <script src="leaving.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Test!
<a href="http://dailypuppy.com" onclick="return leave()">The Daily Puppy</a>
</body>
</html>
```

from this example, if i wanna re-create this where should i be keeping my styles.css file and etc. I am a little confused and could realy use a bit help , thank you.

Comment: I think the problem might lie in somewhere in the media tags try removing then and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 3):

It's dependent on your file structure. Conventionally, if you keep .html files in the root directory, you'd keep style files (.css) in a directory labeled *css* so your structure would like

```
/-
 - /img
 - /css
 | --- style.css
 | --- printstyle.css
 - index.html
```

which means your tag line would read

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/printstyles.css">
```

**Please note the "./" preceding the directory name.** This means it's a relative location and is needed if you're reading your .html files locally (using file:/// instead of serving them via a local server as I imagine you are).

Comment: so i shoud just basically printthe working directory of that file there?

Comment: If you're opening the html files locally you'll need to use relative addresses (./) which tells the browser to start in the current directory. If you want to go up a directory you'd say "../". Up two directories is "../../". But this sort of relative navigation is required because you aren't technically working from the root of your machine which is what your browser will assume if you don't add the "./". Does that answer your question?

Comment: if im keeping the file in a directory called css and i am keeping the html code in a directory called bitstarter. So i should say ./../css/mycssfile.css

Comment: Yes - that would work, but it could be simplified as just "../css/mycssfile.css"

Comment: thank you isick, one last remaining question: if i am going up multiple directories,  do i need to write the directory name after "../" each time? eg: ../directory1/../directory2/../css/myfile.css

Answer (score 0):

Given the example you've posted there, the HTML file and style sheets should reside in the same directory, e.g. Somefolder/index.html and Somefolder/styles.css