# Css doesn't work properly when is in other folder

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've using bootstrap and file and folders is like this

```
root/css/..
```

When I include `<link id="bs-css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` it is working for files in root folder. But if I have file in another folder and trying to include css doesn't work. It doesn't show any style. For example

```
root/users/profile.php
```

then I include in profile.php like this

```
<link id="bs-css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I've also tryed full path again didn't work properly. But if I put inside `/users/` css file or full folder is working `href="css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Comment: try checking with step one by one, it is the path issue only.

Comment: Do you have another style that overrides your style in css file?

Comment: add to that file `<?php echo getcwd() . "\n"; ?>` what does it say?

Comment: Typing the absolute path in browser url does it load file?

Comment: Absolute path is loaded if I type in browser. But if I open `View Source` and click there on css I get 404 error. Very strange

Comment: @DominicTobias `public_html/app/admins/users` the file where I check is is `/users`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linking to an external css file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982936/linking-to-an-external-css-file)

Comment: Sorry but I don't think that is duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the link to be the full path from your URL like this:

```
<link id="bs-css" href="yoursite.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

That should work from any page.

Comment: I've writed in question that I've tried whit full path and didn't work. But if I type directly the uri in browser is load fine css.

Comment: What's the link to your site?

Comment: Sorry but it's not possible to be reached at this momment from outside.

Answer (score 1):

Try using href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"  This should work no matter where your php or html file is located.  This is called a relative path.  So..

```
<link id="bs-css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

As long as css is a direct child of the root, this should find it.

Comment: No style again. The only solution for now is to have second part of `/css/` folder in `/users/` folder which is not good option.

Comment: Maybe it isn't actually root/css?  Could it be root/projectname/css?

Comment: Full path is `/home/venb/public_html/app/admins/css/`. The site which Is in `/app/admins/`

Comment: The public_html will most likely be treated as the root in that file structure.  Try using href="/app/admins/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Comment: Same result. I don't know what to do anymore. I've tryed everything what I found on the internet as solution.

Comment: I would try every version of that full file path, starting at each different folder.  Always remember the / at the beginning of the path.  So try /venb/public_html/app/admins/css, /app/admins/css, etc

Comment: You can use a base href in your html. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_href.asp - that's what I do. If you use an absolute path to your CSS, respond.js won't work.

Comment: @Christina , thank you. Base href actually is working. Still can't understand why this work and all other ways didn't work but at least now is ok.

Comment: A relative path to a file is different based on the location of the document, I have never seen a relative path ../something/style.css work in documents in sub directories unless it's the correct path. Doing this work since 99. I either see a php path (like wordpress uses) or the base href. An absolute path, http://domainname.com/assets/css/styles.css will work but that effs up the respond.js which needs a relative path or a proxy, pain in the arse.

Answer (score 0):

add just **slash** before "css" folder. ex: href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"